# como lo puedo arreglar para que me funcione bien? me manda error en la linea 3 y 8

Tags: java

me falla en la tercer linea y en la 8:

```java
public class radio_de_circulo {
        public static void main( String[] args ) {
                BufferedReader bufEntrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                double num1;
                double resultado;
                System.out.println("escribe el diametro del circulo");
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(bufEntrada.readLine());
                resultado = num1/2;
                System.out.println("el resultado del radio es: "+resultado);
        }
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con arreglar y que funcione bien? ¿Qué errores te genera? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que tiene vs el que esperas? Uno no es adivino para saber que es lo que falla. Por favor, agrégalo a tu pregunta :)

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Edita tu pregunta y añade (ojalá como texto!) los errores que encuentras con tu código. La traza de error. Lo otro: qué pasa si num1 es cero? Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta tanto como necesites para añadir la info relevante, usando la opción bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: *error*? ***Qué error?*** Por otro lado, en java las clases se escriben en `PascalCase`, es decir, la inicial de cada palabra en mayúscula como puedes ver en el nombre del *estilo*, el `snake_case` no se utiliza en Java en principio, excepto algunas cosas muy concretas. Por favor edita la pregunta e indica qué errores tienes, pues no somos adivinos ni llevamos una JVM en la cabeza para analizar código con solo verlo...

Answer (score 2):

Como indica en otra respuesta o indicas la excepción `IOException` en el *main*. Dicha excepción contiene varios saltos de errores, generalmente relacionados con la entrada/salida del programa.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

Otra manera es que captures con un `try catch`. Algunos IDE's resaltan el error y te lo hacen automáticamente por ti, al igual que el primer ejemplo. Quedaría así:

```
    try {
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(bufEntrada.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Si haces la segunda opción recuerda inicializar toda variable que se encuentre fuera y se vaya a usar después, o indicarlo todo en el `try`. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

debes agregar **`IOException`**, prueba en poner esto en el **`main`**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

También recuerda agregar todas las librerías